# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE Query running successfully but no output

Tags: mysql, csv

I am running an SQL statement to read in a CSV file (in this case only 1 column with a heading) and importing it into my database, where further manipulation to the data will occur through subsequent SQL statements.

However, I seem to be unable to load the CSV file into my DB both directly in MySQL Workbench and my PHP website locally as well as on another Mac in my network through the PHP website.

The interesting thing is the query appears to run successfully as I get no errors on any of the platforms or computers but no rows are affected.

I have done a lot of digging in trying to solve the problem. Here is my current SQL code and I will then talk through what I have tried.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/Josh/Desktop/testcsv.csv'
INTO TABLE joinTest
FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES
    TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(interestName);
```

So this is me trying it in MySQL Workbench. In PHP I have an uploader and variable which stores the location of the tmp file. This works as have echo'd it out and all looks fine.

I've tried running it as

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
```

But it still doesn't affect any rows (runs successfully). I've also changed the `TERMINATED BY` in `LINES` to just `\n` but still will not affect any rows.

I can't understand why it is not affecting any rows as my CSV file is readable by all and should be in the correct format (created in Excel and saved as cvs format).

Does anyone know what the potential problem could be?

If any more info is required I will respond with it ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: I think excel saves the file with a semicolon ";" as separator, try to change this in your sql

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately that doesn't work, just tried it and getting the same result, successful query but no rows affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so I discovered Mac uses different Line Endings to Unix & Windows. I opened the CSV in Sublime Text 3 and discovered there was an option to change the Line Endings in the View Options.

I set this to Unix, saved the file and the terminator of \n worked. Unfortunately Sublime text doesn't show the line endings as visible characters so this was purely by chance.

I hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue, make sure the line endings of the CSV match the line endings you are specifying in your LOAD DATA query.